# How to get the value of a variable within an html tag in flask?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am building an app using Flask to show nearby shops, and the user can like a shop so it can be added to their liked shops list.

My question is how can i get the value inside the `<h4>` tag sent to Python knowing that the name attribute is a variable. The html code is below:

```
<form name='likeF' method='POST' action ='{{url_for("liked")}}'>
    <h4 name="ShopName_{{loop.index}}">{{item.ShopName}}</h4>
    <p>
       Shop Description : {{item.ShopDesc}} <br>        
       <button type="submit"  class="success button like">Like</button>
       distance: {{item.ShopDistance}}
    </p>
</form>
```

So please how am I supposed to get back the value of `{{item.ShopName}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send the text inside an `<h4>` tag (or any tag that is not a form input) back to the server, at least not without using Javascript. The easiest method would be to duplicate it in a hidden input element inside the form, such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ShopName" value="{{ item.ShopName }}">
```

Then you can access it using `request.form["ShopName"]`.