# Get variable from button in html into Flask

Tags: html, forms, flask, get, jinja2

I'm attempting to get the invoice number from a button. This number changes with Jinja. I've looked at the following answer but it's not helping. Nothing is printing. Can someone please help?

[How to get the value of a variable within an html tag in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211194/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-within-an-html-tag-in-flask)

HTML

```
<form><th><Button class="btn btn-dark" name="invoice_no" value="{{ i.invoice_no }}">Select Invoice</Button></th></form>
```

Flask

```
if request.method == "POST":

    #  Retrieve invoice number from button
    if request.form.get('invoice_no'):
        invoice = request.form.get('invoice_no')
        print(invoice)
        print("print test")
```

Output is correct: invoice_no=3

```
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2022 20:17:43] "GET /transactions?invoice_no=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: You pass variables within the URL as query parameters with a get request, not in the body of a post request. To get these values use `request.args`.

Comment: I changed it to 'if request.args('invoice_no'):' and nothing changed. Also I've used request.form.get within the body of other pages and it works fine?

Comment: Your log entry shows a GET request with url parameters.
If you want to use post, it is necessary to assign the value `POST` to the `method` attribute of the form.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so don't forget to put method="post" within the form tag. Thank you Detlef.