# Flask, read image path

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form like this

```
<form id="imageForm" method="post" action="/printDDT">
                <img name=imageFile src={{DDTimage}} width="50%" height="50%">
                <br/><br/>
                <button type="submit">Print DDT</button>
</form>
```

and I want to read the `src` in my post function in app.py
I tried this

```
@app.route("/printDDT", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def printDDT():
    if request.method == "POST":
        imageFile = request.files.get('imageFile')
        print(secure_filename[imageFile.filename])
        fileList = updateFile()
        DDTimage = os.path.join(app.config['JPG_FOLDER'], 'ddt.jpg')
        return render_template('home.html', fileList=fileList, DDTimage=DDTimage)
```

but I got

```
File "app.py", line 73, in printDDT
    print(secure_filename[imageFile.filename])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
In the end I followe this strategy [How to get the value of a variable within an html tag in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211194/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-within-an-html-tag-in-flask)

Maybe not the cleanest solution but definitely the smartest.

Comment: Try this instruction: `imageFile = request.files['imageFile']` instead of your: `imageFile = request.files.get('imageFile')`

Comment: @frankfalse I got a Bad Request error. `127.0.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2022 10:04:41] "POST /printDDT HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Comment: I added the solution to my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <input type=file name=file>
  <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

Can you try ?

```py
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
return """""
```

Comment: yep I'm trying right now

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/    You can rearrange them by following them here